# jQuery OnMouseMove scroll div Top/Bottom, NOT right/left, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery

please how to change this code?
http://jsbin.com/alokat/1/edit
I need scroll Up and Down, not Left and Right. Thanks for reply.

Comment: I need to scroll Up/Down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adjusted your code a little:

```
    galW   = $gal.outerWidth(true),
    galSW  = $gal[0].scrollWidth,
```

to

```
    galW   = $gal.outerHeight(true),
    galSW  = $gal[0].scrollHeight,
```

and changed the offset for the `mousemove`.

Also you need to change `$gal.scrollLeft(posX*wDiff);` in `setInterval` to `$gal.scrollTop(posX*wDiff);`.

You can see all chnages here: http://jsbin.com/alokat/102/

Answer (score 1):

This works http://jsbin.com/alokat/109/edit. Should rename the variables and methods though.